# Is it possible to pick next row's cell value on same column if condition not matched?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table `flaggedcomment` and a table `price`.

In `flaggedcomment`, there are two empty columns `Price_DateTime` and `Price_Open` which I want to copy from `price`, depending on the `ON` conditions. Query as below.

```
UPDATE flaggedcomment as t1 
        LEFT JOIN price as t2 
             ON t1.Ticker_Ticker_ID = t2.Ticker_Ticker_ID AND t1.Comment_DateTime = t2.Price_DateTime
SET t1.Price_DateTime = t2.Price_DateTime, t1.Price_Open = t2.Price_Open
```

This query will leave some cells with null value because there's no match between `t1.Comment_DateTime` and `t2.Price_DateTime`.

Is there a way to "pick" the next available `Price_DateTime` if there's no match found?

For example, if the value of `t1.Comment_DateTime` is `2014-09-29 20:44:00` but it's not exist in `t2.Price_DateTime`, can I pick the next row's `Price_DateTime` value, e.g. `2014-09-30 08:00:00`?

I am new to deal with MySQL queries and I've tried my best in explaining what I want to do. If I didn't explain my question well, please let me know and I will try to explain it further.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean you want to find the "first" row with same `Ticker_ID` and same or bigger `DateTime`, first when ordered by DateTime ascending. One way to do this, assuming that the `price` table has a unique constraint on `(Ticker_Ticker_ID, Price_DateTime)`:

```
UPDATE flaggedcomment AS fc 
    INNER JOIN price AS p
        ON  p.Ticker_Ticker_ID = fc.Ticker_Ticker_ID 
        AND p.Price_DateTime = 
            ( SELECT pi.Price_DateTime
              FROM price AS pi
              WHERE pi.Ticker_Ticker_ID = fc.Ticker_Ticker_ID 
                AND pi.Price_DateTime >= fc.Comment_DateTime
              ORDER BY pi.Price_DateTime ASC
              LIMIT 1
            ) 
SET
    fc.Price_DateTime = p.Price_DateTime, 
    fc.Price_Open = p.Price_Open ;
```

Comment: Hi ypercube, thank you for your help! this does the trick! :D